# Составить последовательность по формуле

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть такое задание:
Для последовательности A1 = 1, An+1 = An + 1/(1 + An) составить программу печати k-ого члена в виде обыкновенной несократимой дроби. Например, A2 = 3/2, A3 = 19/10.

Программу смогу написать сам, не могу разобраться, откуда берутся числа A2 = 3/2, A3 = 19/10. Если считать по формуле: A2 = 1 + 1/(1 + 1) = 3/3, A3 = 2 + 1/(1 + 2) = 3/3. Откуда числа 3/2, 19/10? Как их получить?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 5):

```
A2 = 1 + 1/(1 + 1) = 1 + 1/2 = 2/2 + 1/2 = (2+1)/2 = 3/2

A3 = A2 + 1/(1 + A2) = 3/2 + 1/(1 + 3/2) = 3/2 + 1 / (2/2 + 3/2) = 3/2 + 1 /(5/2) = 3/2 + 2/5 = 15/10 + 4/10 = (15+4)/10 = 19/10
```

Comment: Пойдёт, добавить точку с запятой, что б в плюсах собралось.

Comment: ну тогда надо еще тип A2 и A3 написать :D